# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'decormoi' SQL Error: 1044, SQLState: 42000

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, application.properties

I know there are many similar questions but none answer mine.

I get this error when i try to connect to the database in launch my app.

2020-07-08 18:18:26.266 ERROR 33384 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'decormoi'

I have already granted all privileges as seen in other questions but NOTHING!!!

***my application.properties***

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/decormoi
spring.datasource.username = root 
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql = true      
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Please, Help!!!

Comment: Have you tried logging in to the DB with the same user outside your application, like MySQL workbench?

Comment: probleme résolu!!!!!!! je devais changer les autorisations dans phpmyadmin dans information-shéma.